# How can i check if a directory contains a file in groovy

Tags: file, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a case or directory that contains a huge number of files i want a command in groovy or a method that can check all the files in my directory that contains the letter "h" in their name and return me a list of these files name

```
def findFilesWithModulesH(def steps, def target) {
    def filesWithModulesH = []
    new File(target).eachFile { file ->
        steps.println "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0 ${file}"
        def fileLabel = file.name.tokenize("-")[0].toUpperCase()

>    if(!filesWithModulesH.contains(fileWithModulesH)){
>                 filesWithModulesH.add(fileWithModulesH)
>             }
>         }
>     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this.

**Method 01: Using `findFiles` Jenkins utility function**

```
def folder = 'folder/path'
def fileNameList = []
dir(folder) {
    def fileList = findFiles(glob: '*h*')
    fileList.each { fileNameList.add(it.name) }
    
}
println fileNameList
```

**Method 2: Using Groovy**

Note the `@NonCPS` annotation in the function

```
@NonCPS
def getFiles(def path) {
                    
    def filesWithH = []
    new File(path).traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES, maxDepth: 0) { file ->
        if (file.name.contains('h')) {
            filesWithH << file.name
        }
    }
    return filesWithH
}
```

Comment: Second method is a bit problematic as `new File(path)` will always search for the path on the master node - regardless of the current agent that executing the pipeline.

Comment: thank you very much indeed, i needed to add @NonCPS

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pure groovy equivalent of the `findFiles` step you would need to use Jenkins `FilePath` class:

```
import hudson.FilePath

def getFiles(String path) {
    def filePath = new FilePath(Jenkins.get().getComputer(env.NODE_NAME).channel, path)
    return filePath.list('*h*')
}
```

No need to make the method `@NonCPS`, since all variables are serializable.